# How can I self-join two sets of tokenised data to indicate match frequency

Tags: join, sql-server-2008-r2

Here's the scenario.

I have two records in a SQL Server 2008 R2 table as follows:

```
ID                    Name
1                     Joe Stephen Brown     
2                     Joe Henry Wallace Brown     
3                     Jerry Joe Carr     
4                     Jerry Lewis
```

I've tokenised the name column and put it in a token table, along with the id that the token is associated with, so that we now have this:

```
ID                    Token
1                     Joe
1                     Stephen
1                     Brown
2                     Joe
2                     Henry
2                     Wallace
2                     Brown
3                     Jerry
3                     Joe
3                     Carr
4                     Jerry
4                     Lewis
```

I'd like to be able to do a self join on this table so that I could count the number of times that a token from one table in the self join matches a token from the other table in the self join. So the matches should be like this:

```
Table1.ID             Table1.Token          Table2.ID             Table2.Token
1                     Joe                   2                     Joe
1                     Brown                 2                     Brown
1                     Joe                   3                     Joe
3                     Jerry                 4                     Jerry
```

*(There are two token matches ('Joe' and 'Brown') on records 1 and 2, one ('Joe') on records 1 and 3, and one ('Jerry') on records 3 and 4.)*

So I would like the final report of matches to be like this:

```
Table1.ID             Table2.ID             Number of matches
1                     2                     2
1                     3                     1
3                     4                     1
```

However, I'm stumped on how to do this. I thought of doing a self join on the tokens alone, but it becomes complicated if there are other records with 'Joe' and 'Brown' in the token table.

**EDIT**

If there is a scenario like this:

```
ID                    Name
1                     Joe Stephen Brown     
2                     Joe Henry Brown Brown
```

I would want the match count to be 2, if possible; in other words, the 'Brown' in 'Joe Stephen Brown' should match the first 'Brown' in 'Joe Henry Brown Brown', and the second 'Brown' in 'Joe Henry Brown Brown' should remain unmatched. Then both the 'Joe' > 'Joe' and 'Brown' > first 'Brown' matches should be counted.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the results you're expecting if there's more than two tokens of the same value?  I'm not sure if you're wanting just a count of the tokens, or if you want to see a Cartesian product of each token joined to all other tokens of the same value...

Comment: I've added clarification, @michael-frederickson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand the requirements, I believe this query should give the expected results:

```
;WITH DistinctTokens AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, Name
    FROM Tokens
)
SELECT
    t1.ID AS [Table1.ID],
    t1.Token AS [Table1.Token],
    t2.ID AS [Table2.ID],
    t2.Token AS [Table2.Token]
FROM
    DistinctTokens t1 FULL OUTER JOIN
    DistinctTokens t2 ON t1.Token = t2.Token AND t1.ID < t2.ID
```

EDIT:

OK, thanks for the clarification; is this closer?

```
SELECT
    t1.ID AS [Table1.ID],
    t2.ID AS [Table2.ID],
    COUNT(*) AS [Number of matches]
FROM
    Tokens t1 JOIN
    Tokens t2 ON t1.Token = t2.Token AND t1.ID < t2.ID
GROUP BY
    t1.ID,
    t2.ID
```

Comment: Thanks. @michael-fredrickson, but that's not quite the answer I'm looking for. I can see that the example I gave showing the matching was confusing, and the example I gave was too simple to fully explain what I'm trying to achieve. I've again edited the original question to make it even clearer what I want.